# Is this clear? vs. Is that clear? vs. Is it clear?

Tags: grammar

I cannot get the difference between *Is **this** clear?*, *Is **that** clear?* and *Is **it** clear?*. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: The real Charles Bronson would have shot first, and only then asked questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"Is this clear?"*** - An inquiry which seeks to determine if an object or subject under current scrutiny is transparent - literally or, figuratively.

***"Is it clear?"*** - An inquiry which seeks to determine if an object or subject, which may, or, may not be, under current scrutiny is transparent - literally or, figuratively.

***"Is that clear?*** - An admonition to gain compliance; usually assumed to be a veiled threat.